# How to fix Uncaught TypeError: $image.cropper is not a function

Tags: jquery, django, cropperjs

I got the error of  `Uncaught TypeError: $image.cropper is not a function` in my project when using the cropper jQuery plugin: https://github.com/fengyuanchen/jquery-cropper

I guess the error has to do with the order defining jQuery, Bootstrap and Cropper files.
After several attempts , i could not define the correct order.

My order is:

```
<script src="/static/theme/assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/theme/assets/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/cropper/js/jquery-cropper.js"></script>
```

If it helps , my project has to do with cropping images in a django application based on the tutorial: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/03/02/how-to-crop-images-in-a-django-application.html

Here is the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $image.cropper is not a function
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> ((index):425)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDivElement.y.handle (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.trigger (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at w.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at w.fn.init.trigger (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDivElement.o (bootstrap.bundle.min.js:6)
    at HTMLDivElement.i (jquery.min.js:2)


 Uncaught TypeError: $image.cropper is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> ((index):451)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLButtonElement.y.handle (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Comment: Your path to cropper.js is wrong. You need to correct it

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan why you think that?. The error comes after uploading my image

Comment: Because the error is saying that the library is not being loaded. You've clearly got a script reference to it, so the most common mistake in that scenario is that your path is wrong. It's also possible you're including another jQuery.js reference after those you include in the question, so the cropper reference is being lost

Comment: My problem was that I had 3 ***jquery.min.js*** imported. 2 In the head and 1 in the body, so I commented out the one in the body and one in the head. After importing 1 ***jquery.min.js***   the error was gone.